# Is there any IDE for crystal report?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have developed a windows application using .net and crystal report..

Now I want to install an IDE such that I can edit the crystal reports as per individual client's requirenment..

My Development Environment..

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Crystal report runtime -13 - 32 bit

Hence, Is there any IDE to to so?

Regards,
Mahesh Lalwani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course:

[SAP Crystal Reports 2011](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sme/business-intelligence-crystal-solutions/sap-crystal-reports/index.epx).
You can manage more parameters; reports created are fully compatible.

It is not free; if you need a free solution must install **Visual Studio Express and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio**.

I know, each client hai his own requirements for reports; is typical trouble.. actually hard to solve!
I use 3 ways:
 1 **Report designed from us**, client's logo is loaded dynamically from DB (one folder contains default reports, one folder each client version)
 2 **Full data export** to excel-csv (so users create reports on MS Office)
 3 **Report designed by user**
 An HTML editor to the user
     -    The user enters HTML using `HTML Web Editor` (like [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/))
     -    `HTML` is stored in a DB table
     -    Report query is executed, `HTML` is loaded from DB
     -    Some markers, defined for each report are replaced from query data (i.e. `#ReportTitle#` or `#Money#`) so styling and data are merged
     -   Final `HTML` is shown using a text area in `CrystalReports`, with `HTML` formatting [careful, there are [few limitations](http://www.clearcutreports.com/2009/08/07/supported-crystal-html-tags/).

Comment: oh its not freeware.. is there any other tool which is freeware??

Comment: No, no free tool; if you need free one must install Visual Studio Express and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio

Comment: I want to install on client machine so installing Visual Studio Express will it be good idea?? I think its not good idea to install dev tool on client machine

Comment: I agree, not GOOD idea.. but FREE idea! I can't find more solutions instead.

Comment: Calling Crystal Reports an IDE is a huge stretch.

Comment: @craig I know,but in my case what else solution I can provide as each of my client will ask for different formatting in crystal reports.

Comment: @mahesh look at my imprevod solution!

Comment: There are no good free solutions. We are using two ways: 1) (re)design reports ourselves for little fee; 2) convince customer to buy at least one license for SAP Crystal Reports (simplest version). In addition some our templates are having placeholder for company logo and our code can load images dynamically into these placeholders.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco seen the new solutions!! Good options but not hwppy because of limitation so currently I have decided that I will provide individual reports design to my client as per his requirement..